# AllowHtml with PRG pattern in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I can't get the `AllowHtml` attribute  (used in the `DirtySearch` class) to work with the following actions:

```
    public ActionResult NewEntry(string searchIndex, string searchString)
    {
        var model = new SearchResultsModel(loserID, searchIndex, searchString);
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetSearchResults(DirtySearch dirtySearch)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("NewEntry", new { searchIndex = dirtySearch.SearchIndex, searchString = dirtySearch.SearchString });
    }
```

I'm receiving the *A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (%)* error.

I've included the `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` in my Web.config, and put `ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider();` in the `Application_Start` method.

I feel as though I'm overlooking something obvious here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not suppress this error. It seems you have a security problem because of the PATH still having a problem. What is the path (check fiddler so you can see all the request details)
taken from:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/11/09/mvc3-granular-request-validation-update.aspx

"the granular request validation in MVC 3 only supports turning off validation for Form (and sometimes QueryString). Path will still be validated, as well as the remaining Request collections.

Your module should access the Request values via the System.Web.Helpers.Validation.Unvalidated() method (available in System.Web.WebPages.dll) to get around the default request validation (that's what's being used by the mechanism that allows AllowHtml to work)."

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'm struggling a bit with this partial explanation: "...the granular request validation in MVC 3 only supports turning off validation for Form (**and sometimes QueryString**). Path will still be validated, as well as the remaining Request collections."

Answer (score 0):

You can probably suppress this error if you put an additional attribute on the `httpRuntime` node in your `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
</system.web>
```

But you better read the documentation to understand what security features will be turned off by these settings.

Comment: This would then apply to everything, though, whereas I was hoping for a finer stroke.